# Plot : type=n is not showing any figure in R

Tags: r, plot

```
control=data.frame(replicate(16,sample(0:1,111,rep=TRUE)))    
control.tendon <- control[,seq(2, 16, 1)]   
index <- rep(1, 15) %x% seq(1, 111, 1)
plot(index, c(10, rep(35, 1664)), xlab="Minutes",
ylab="Temperature (Degrees Celcius)", pch=subject, type="n")
for(i in 1:15) {
lines(seq(1, 111, 1), unlist(control.tendon[i]), col="red",

        lty=i)
}
```

I should get an empty figure but nothing pops out. If anyone can help I would be very glad.

Comment: It's hard to say without more information—I just tried this on my system and got an empty figure.

Comment: Do you want to draw a line or point?

Comment: I want to draw multiple line in a same plot. I have modified the question with more details. If you can help it would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Mistake is in `type = "n"`. That suggest to draw just frame where line or graph can be added in next statement.

If you dig into `help` you will find:
`"n" for no plotting.`

The `type = "n"` is used when you want to draw multiple graphs (say lines) on same plot then `type = "n"` can be used prepare the layout with limits and label of axis. This will follow with `line` and other statement to add graphs.

Modified code like:

```
plot(index, c(10, rep(35, 1664)), xlab="Minutes",
     ylab="Temperature (Degrees Celcius)", pch="1", type="l")
```

It will work.

**Note:**

The value of `pch` is not correctly used in OP. `Help` suggests `pch` to be an `integer` or single character.

```
*pch
Either an integer specifying a symbol or a single character to be
used as the default in plotting points. See points for possible values
and their interpretation. Note that only integers and single-character
strings can be set as a graphics parameter (and not NA nor NULL).

Some functions such as points accept a vector of values which are recycled.*
```

Comment: Actually I know that what "n" stands for. But I want to pop up the figure first then the line plot. I have modified the question. Please have look.

Comment: @MithunGhosh Perhaps you have not noticed that I have changed value of `pch` as well. Please correct `pch` value in your code.

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice that. But when I restart R all things pop up with the code( That I mentioned in the question). Thanks for your help. Much appreciated.

Comment: @MithunGhosh Your code will still not work until `subject` is assigned correctly before execution of `plot`. Good that your problem is fixed.